# Валидация формы django

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

Моя форма возвращает правильные данные

<QueryDict: {'Id_Incidents': ['50'], 'Type_Participation': ['p'], 'Id_People': ['1'], 'Competencies': ['рн']}>

Но форма при этом не является валидной, ошибка status=400. Правильный ли я возвращаю формат данных от QueryDict? Я пробовал удалять все дополнительные поля из модели, создавая/применяя миграции, но это не дало положительных результатов.

Views.py

```
def add_person(request):
        id_incidents = request.session.get('Id_Incidents', 'ничего не передано')
        if request.method == "POST":
            if request.user:
                form = AkpGroupForm(request.POST)  # форма, созданная в forms.py чтобы добавить участника
                print(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    # group_created = form['Group'].save(commit=False)
                    # group_created.Id_Incidents = get_object_or_404(AkpIncidents, Id_Incidents=id_incidents)
                    # group_created.save()
                    Id_Incidents = form.cleaned_data['Id_Incidents']
                    Id_People = form.cleaned_data['Id_People']
                    Competencies = form.cleaned_data['Competencies']
                    Type_Participation = form.cleaned_data['Type_Participation']
                    new_person = AkpGroup(
                        Id_Incidents=Id_Incidents,
                        Id_People=Id_People,
                        Competencies=Competencies,
                        Type_Participation=Type_Participation,
                    )
                    new_person.save()
                    return HttpResponse(status=201)
                else:
                    return HttpResponse(status=400)
```

Models.py

```
class AkpGroup(models.Model):
Id_Group = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='Идентификатор участника группы АКП')
Id_Incidents = models.ForeignKey('AkpIncidents', models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='Идентификатор инцидента')
# stage 3 fields
Id_People = models.ManyToManyField('AkpPeople', verbose_name='Ф.И.О. участника')
Competencies = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name='Компетенции')

LOAN_TYPE_PARTICIPATION = (
    ('d', 'Руководитель группы'),
    ('p', 'Член группы')
)
Type_Participation = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=LOAN_TYPE_PARTICIPATION, default='p',
                                      verbose_name='Тип участия')
# Вспомогательные
Change_Time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Время изменения')
Change_User = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Пользователь, внесший изменения')
Del_Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Дата удаления')
Del_User = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Пользователь, удаливший данные')

Is_Delete = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Удален')
Is_Posted = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Опублековано')

objects = models.Manager()

def display_id_people(self):
    """
    Creates a string for the Genre. This is required to display genre in Admin.
    """
    return ', '.join([Id_People.Name for Id_People in self.Id_People.all()[:10]])
display_id_people.short_description = 'AkpGroup'

def __str__(self):
    return self.Competencies

class Meta:
    db_table = 'Akp_Group'
    verbose_name = 'Группа АКП'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Группы АКП'
```

html

```
<tfoot>
        <form id="form_person_add" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <tr>
                <th scope="row"></th>
                <th scope="row"></th>
                <th scope="col">{{form.Group.Id_Incidents}}</th>
                <th scope="col">{{form.Group.Type_Participation}}</th>
                <th scope="col">{{form.Group.Id_People}}</th>
                <th scope="col">{{form.Group.Competencies}}</th>
                <td>
                    <button type="submit">Добавить</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Scripts

```
function add_person(e) {
        const dataToBackEnd = new FormData();

        let idIncidents = $("#id_Group-Id_Incidents").val();
        let idParticipation = $("#id_Group-Type_Participation").val();
        let idPeople = $("#id_Group-Id_People").val();
        let competencies = $("#id_Group-Competencies").val();

        dataToBackEnd.append("Id_Incidents", idIncidents);
        dataToBackEnd.append("Type_Participation", idParticipation);
        dataToBackEnd.append("Id_People", idPeople);
        dataToBackEnd.append("Competencies", competencies);

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/main/url_to_django/add_person/",
            headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value },
            data: dataToBackEnd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            dataType: "json",
        }).done(function(data) {
            loadDataForTable();
        });

    }

    $formAdd.on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        add_person(e);
    });

    // execution
    loadDataForTable();
})();
```

Urls.py

```
app_name = "main"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.start, name="start"),
    path('group', views.Groups.as_view(), name='group'),
    
    path(
        'url_to_django/add_person/',
        views.add_person,
        name='add_person'),
```

Comment: добавьте код формы

Comment: я добавил код формы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причиной моих долгих и мучительных бед было использование связи ManyToManyField, при замене на ForeignKey все успешно работает. Проанализировав, пришел к выводу, что связь многие ко многим здесь пожалуй не требуется.

Answer (score 0):

Начните с понимания того, что именно не валидно

```
if form.is_valid():
        return HttpResponse('All Good!')
    else:
        return HttpResponse(form.errors.values())  # Validation failed
```

Скорее всего проблема в ключах Id_Incidents и/или Id_People.
Смущает если честно foreignkey от models.DO_NOTHING. Что это должно означать?

И коли уж используете форму, ей и создавайте запись в модели.

Comment: Response: 
 <ul class="errorlist"><li>Введите список значений.</li></ul>.
foreignkey от models.DO_NOTHING - Смысл в том, чтобы при удалении связанной записи в другой модели, запись в текущей модели оставалась без изменений, хотя в данном случае, исходя из логики программы можно и удалять.